# Is this a safe, inexpensive way to do auto-versioning on an ASP.NET web page? Or will it bite me?

Tags: c#, asp.net, auto-versioning

I've got an ASP.NET web page where I want to ensure users get the latest version of the javascript file each time they load the page, but I do not want them to download the file unless it's actually changed.  It is a continually evolving web app and the js files get modified frequently. I have a version number in the url that I update manually.  But I keep forgetting to update it when I change the js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Sched.js?v=1"></script>
```

So doing some searching for auto-versioning methods, I found one using re-writes and php, which made me think about my environment.  The only thing I came up with was to use the LastWriteTime of the js file for the version.  So I built a function:

```
    protected string GetFileTime(string file)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(file));
        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
            return fi.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToFileTime().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("0");
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

And changed my script url in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Sched.js?dev=<%= GetFileTime("js/Sched.js") %>"></script>
```

It seems to work great on my dev server. The browser sees this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Sched.js?dev=131969009464369343"></script>
```

I've tested it with many page loads and the number remains the same until I make a change to the file.

So it seems like a great solution. I've looked at FileInfo and it reads the file meta data from the disk and does not open or lock the file.  But when I put it live on the production server with about 1000 users, is there a possibility of performance or other issues?

Comment: Are you updating JavaScript but not any of the server side code?  I only inquire because even with my SPA's my package.json is keeping track and versioning everything.

Comment: @Greg Yes. Mostly updating the js file and possibly html. But server-side code only occasionally gets changed and recompiled if I have to add a new WebMethod for an ajax call.

Comment: And you are not using a package.json?

Comment: Never heard of it before. I just looked it up and it has something to do with node.js and npm, neither of which i'm familiar with.  This is just a plain-jane asp.net website with a few js and css files.

Comment: 1,000 users won't be a problem IMO. However from server perspective I will try to avoid touching hard drive as much as I can. You can always add a cache/use FileMonitor if it becomes a problem later. FYI, ASP.NET Core asp-append-version uses hash code + file change monitor.

Comment: Package.json holds all that information and is JSON so can be easily parsed by Asp.Net.